# Generic Error Page not decorated

Tags: spring, servlets, error-handling, sitemesh

I have a generic error page which is not decorated by SiteMesh.

May I know what is the reason ?

```
<filter>
  <display-name>SiteMesh_Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>SiteMesh_Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SiteMesh_Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly provide any guidance. Please let me know if need further information.

Comment: Do you use Sitemesh 2 or 3? Your filter configuration is for Sitemesh 2 while in your comment to @kschneid you say you use Sitemesh 3. So which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://web.archive.org/web/20120422070138/http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/SIM-168) is the most recent archive of the original issue.

[This](https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh2/pull/12) is the closed issue page.

So, it looks like you need to make sure that you're not using a release that's more than 2 years old :), and you need to make sure that your SiteMesh filter is configured to process error pages by including:

```
<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
```

along with whatever else you need...

Comment: I have add it but it failed to decorated too. What wrong with it '

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using Sitemesh 3 as a decorator. Your configuration in the questions tells me you're using Sitemesh 2, but you mentioned using Sitemesh 3 in the comment to @kschneid answer.

Sitemesh 3 uses a `Selector` implementation to select which requests it can buffer (decorate).  By default this is the `org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.BasicSelector`. This selector has two constructors namely:

```
public BasicSelector(String... mimeTypesToBuffer) {
    this(false, mimeTypesToBuffer);
}

public BasicSelector(boolean includeErrorPages, String... mimeTypesToBuffer) {
    this.mimeTypesToBuffer = mimeTypesToBuffer;
    this.includeErrorPages = includeErrorPages;
}
```

The former is used by the `BaseSiteMeshFilterBuilder` to construct the selector by default. This means the `includeErrorPages` property will be set to `false` and only pages with a status of *200 OK* will be buffered by the filter. To overcome this you will need to somehow use the other constructor and set `includeErrorPages` to `true`.

This can be done by subclassing `org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter` and override the protected `applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder)` method ending up with a method similar to:

```
public class ErrorPageEnabledSiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
    @Override
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        builder.setCustomSelector(new BasicSelector(true, "text/html", "application/xhtml+xml", "application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"))
    }
}
```

The above will instruct the builder to use the custom selector which now will decorate error pages. The only thing left is to add a instance of `ErrorPageEnabledSiteMeshFilter` to your `ServletContext` replacing the old one.