# How to enable detailstheme to be applied on error page generated by exception handling?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have used Spring MVC Exception Handling. 
modified the web.xml like

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>

@Controller
class GeneralErrorHandlerController {

    @RequestMapping("error")    
    public String handelError(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
         /**
      * Process the error details received in the request
     */

     // Lets get the status code and uri from the request
     final Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");      
     String requestUri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
          if (requestUri == null) {
        requestUri = "Unknown";
      }
      // create a message to be sent back via the model object.
      final String message = MessageFormat.format("{0} returned for {1}", 
        statusCode, requestUri); 

       model.addAttribute("errorMessage", message);
        return "Common/Error/globalError";
    }
}
```

but details theme is not applied on return views. so please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: You must design an error page exactly the same way you do for every other page. If you do this your theme will be applied. Maybe you could post more information?

Comment: my problem is Spring and SiteMesh Error Page is not decorated (skips main filters). you may refere the same problem like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593607/spring-and-sitemesh-error-page-is-not-decorated-skips-main-filters

Comment: Well obviously you do not catch the http errors. In my project I implemented an abstract base class which catches ALL http errors and redirects to a standardized error page. Siehe answer below

Comment: not able to get it. i have folowed following steps defined in url https://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc .. my problem is detailstheme is not applied at error page .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. I implemented an abstract base class for all my controllers. This base class has a routine to handle all http errors the servlet encounter.

```
    @ExceptionHandler()
    public ModelAndView handleException(ServletException exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

    // populate your modell with data, choose errorpage etc.

    }
```

Comment: how to use it? where will be the error handler mapping ?

Comment: THIS is the error handling. As I said if you put this in your controller (preferrably in a base controller which inherits this method to all other controllers you have) all http errors are caught and your error page is shown.